# Add item in Outliner RMB context menu

Tags: python, interface

How do I add two items in the RMB context menu when right clicking in the outliner?
I want them at the position of this red line:

[image]

There should be a separator after "Deselect" and before "Unlink" and in between I want to have the Batch rename (bpy.ops.wm.batch_rename()) operator and a flyout called "Rename utilities".

[image: The Batch Rename operator is the same as in from Edit > Batch Rename]

So the menu would look like this:

---

- Copy
- Paste

---

- Delete
- Delete Hierarchy

---

- Select
- Select Hierarchy
- Deselect

---

- Batch Rename
- Rename Utilities >

---

- Unlink
- etc.

Rename Utilities would several operators that I am currently working on. How do I add those to the menu position (1) or position (2) or position (-1)? And how do I add break lines in between?

Comment: You can't. The available UI only allows you to add menu entries at the top or bottom. There are no interfaces for inserting or reordering.

Comment: Then how do I add these two items at the top of the menu?

Comment: use `prepend` instead of `append`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general way to add a new entry to a menu has two parts, the draw function
for your menu entry, and a call to the menu type to add your draw function.

In this example `TOPBAR_MT_` is a prefix indicating that the menu of interest is one of those on the top bar.  The example uses the `File` menu and added an entry to the `import` submenu.  For your second screenshot, you would change `file_import` to `edit`.  You can find this out by enable dev extras in preferences and hovering over the Edit menu.  If you want the entry at the top instead of the bottom, use `prepend` instead of `append`.

```py
def menu_item_draw_func(self, context):
    # Replace the next line with your menu draw code
    # self.layout.operator()


def register():
    # replace TOPBAR_MT_file_import with the name of the menu you want
    # to add your menu item to.  append adds to the end, prepend to the
    # start
    # bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_import.append(menu_item_draw_func)
```